# Mysql group by join wrong result

Tags: mysql, join

I not figure out to evaluate the maximum creation date value in a join. Below the tables envolved:

- Supervisor
- SupervisorCompany
- Company

A Supervisor can be related to many Company, and a Company can be related to many Supervisor.
The relation ManyToMany is represented by SupervisorCompany table that conatains the foreign key related.

```
--------------
| Supervisor |
-----------------------------------------------------------
IdSupervisor  |     Name   | Surname |    CreationTime     |
------------------------------------------------------------
1             | Maximilian | Green   | 2022-01-01 01:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------
2             |   Josh     | Nice    | 2023-04-03 01:00:01 | 
------------------------------------------------------------
3             |  Albert    | Cloud   | 2022-03-01 01:32:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------
4             |  Peter     | Dark    | 2022-03-01 01:32:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------

--------------
| Company     |
--------------------------------------
IdCompany     |    Brand   | Address |
--------------------------------------
1             |      X     |         |
--------------------------------------
2             |      Y     |         | 
--------------------------------------
3             |      Z     |         |
--------------------------------------
4             |      J     |         | 
--------------------------------------


-------------------------
| SupervisorCompany     |
--------------------------------------
Id     |Id_Supervisor   | Id_Company |
--------------------------------------
8      |      1         |    1      |
--------------------------------------
9      |      2         |    1      | 
--------------------------------------
10     |      3         |    1      |
--------------------------------------
11     |      4         |    3      | 
--------------------------------------
```

I want return the newest CreationTime Supervisor of a Company for each Company.

I executed this query:

```
select *, MAX(Supervisor.CreationTime) from Company 
    inner join SupervisorCompany on Company.IdCompany = SupervisorCompany.IdCompany 
    inner join Supervisor on SupervisorCompany.IdSupervisor = Supervisor.IdSupervisor 
    GROUP BY Company.IdCompany;
```

But the result is:

```
| Maximilian | Green   | 2022-01-01 01:00:01 |   1   |
```

insted

```
|   Josh     | Nice    | 2023-04-03 01:00:01 |   1   |
```

I know that there is somethings wrong in the query but I don't know exactly what is the mistake.
I tried with a subquery or others approach but I don't figure out.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should select only the company ID and the max creation time:

```sql
SELECT c.IdCompany, MAX(s.CreationTime) AS MaxCreationTime
FROM Company c
INNER JOIN SupervisorCompany sc ON c.IdCompany = sc.IdCompany 
INNER JOIN Supervisor s ON sc.IdSupervisor = s.IdSupervisor 
GROUP BY c.IdCompany;
```

The rough rule of thumb for an aggregation query is that we can select only columns which appear in the `GROUP BY` clause or columns which appear inside aggregate functions (such as `MAX()`).